# Horizontal scaling in Spring cloud

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

How to do Horizontal scaling using spring or spring cloud?
In kubernetes we have replication factor, based on the RC value kubernetes will spin up the containers. In similar lines, is there any feature in spring to scaleup services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud is not a platform and doesn't scale services. You need to use a platform like Cloud Foundry or Kubernetes.